# Images not vertically aligned on smaller screens

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, responsive-images

I struggle with one CSS issue on smaller screens. I would be very grateful for any help.

The problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVLpe.png

Each thumbnail should be always in one column, like that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3r2B.png

URL (only on desktop - on mobile devices there is other slider loaded):

https://abirose.pl/produkt/fiore-s-silver-kolczyki-krotkie-kwiaty-z-perlami/

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: We need to see your code.

Comment: It looks like you're using slick slider. They may be some javascript changing it's layout on smaller screens.

Comment: @dantheman93 - you were right! Slick slider js was messing things up. Thank you for the hint, the issue is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

if your problem in css, you can use flex-box, like this:

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

add this class or style to your parent element.